# How to set a CGFloat to a UILabel's text property

Tags: iphone, text, properties, nsstring, cgfloat

I have a `UILabel` called `optionsDisplayerBrushSizeLabel` who's text property I want to set to a `CGFloat`: `brushSizeVal`. I understand that the text property needs to be a string but I don't know how to convert a CGFloat to an `NSString`.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can try:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%.2f", myFloat];
```

Comment: I think there should [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%.2f", myFloat]; for floats.

Comment: you are entirely correct, I've edited my answer, sorry, a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Tray this in swift

```
var a = String (stringInterpolationSegment:myFloat)
```